# Search for Site in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a form where I can retrieve the information. So far I have implemented a model and a controller with an action query.

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

My controller has:

def query
     @results = Search.search(params[:query] )
   end

And in my models I have:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ['first LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    Customer.find(:all)
  end
end
```

But it give me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SearchesController#query

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: first: SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE (first LIKE '%test%')
```

Why does my code produce this error?

Comment: Do your really have a column named "first" in you Customer model? Could you show db/schema.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you don't have a first column in customers table on the DB.

Did you mean maybe first_name ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Customer.find(:all, :conditions => ["'first' LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
```